# mysql count multiple types with a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "users" where each user has a column "status" containing the value "1" or "2" or "3";

Now with a single mysqli query, I just want to count how many users with status = 1, how many users with status = 2, and how many users with status = 3

NB: The query must be count ONLY and no data has to selected or output except the number of each status.

I found other questions here covering nearly the same topic but they are not exactly the same.

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT status, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY status`

Comment: How come the best answers are often found in the comments section?  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  count(case when status = 1 then 1 else null end) AS STATUS_1,
  count(case when status = 2 then 1 else null end) AS STATUS_2,
  count(case when status = 3 then 1 else null end) AS STATUS_3
FROM users;
```

count will only count non-null entries and case-when will work on other databases as well.

Comment: Thanks for that but shall I use $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); or what as it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by selectivity counting: just use a `CASE` expression inside `count` that only passed a non-null value for the desired rows:

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) status_1
     , count(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) status_2
     , count(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) status_3
  FROM users
```

This is the same as the nicer, but not nativley supported syntax using `FILTER`:

```
SELECT count(*) FILER(WHERE status = 1) status_1
     , count(*) FILER(WHERE status = 2) status_2
     , count(*) FILER(WHERE status = 3) status_3
  FROM users
```

Read more about this on my website modern SQL: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(value=1,1,0)) as one,
SUM(IF(value=2,1,0)) as two,
SUM(IF(value=3,1,0)) as trhee
FROM users
```

The `IF` gives only a '1' back when your values is what you want it to be.